# final variables are not functioning well in jshell

Tags: final, java-9, access-modifiers, jshell

I am working with jshell of JDK9.

I just created a final variable and assigned a value to it.
And in the next line i just modified the value. And to my surprise, there was no error when modifying the final variables.

Here is the code snippets:

```
jshell> final int r = 0;
|  Warning:
|  Modifier 'final'  not permitted in top-level declarations, ignored
|  final int r = 0;
|  ^---^
r ==> 0

jshell> r = 1;
r ==> 1

jshell> System.out.println("r = "+r)
r = 1
```

Is it what is expected from jshell? or there is some other way to work with final variables in jshell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While creating a final variable at the top-level is not supposed to be practiced. But I guess there is no hard way of restricting such usages.

From the documentation around [`JShell.eval`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/JShell.html#eval-java.lang.String-)

> The modifiers `public`, `protected`, `private`, `static`, and `final` are not
>   allowed on *op-level* declarations and are *ignored with a warning*.
>
> Synchronized, native, abstract, and default top-level methods are not
>   allowed and are errors.
>
> If a previous definition of a declaration is
>   overwritten then there will be an event showing its status changed to
>   OVERWRITTEN, this will not occur for dropped, rejected, or already
>   overwritten declarations.

The warning stated above is quite visible when you execute `jshell` in verbose mode as follows:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to suppress these warnings? jshell -s still prints them out.

Comment: I could not reproduce this with JShell 16 and maybe something has changed? I do not see any warnings. Could you please explain me how to use **final** in JShell?